# Вернуть глобальную кнопку телеграмм бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram

Я хочу узнать как вернуть кнопку "Запустить" в телеграмм боте. Все изрыл, сложность в том что я не знаю как она может называться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Просто удалите всю историю сообщений с ботом и снизу появится кнопка "Запустить". По сути, эта кнопка просто отправляет команду /start

Comment: Я чистил историю, но кнопка так и не появилась, разве что если удалить чат.

Comment: Ну так Вы и сами ответили на свой вопрос

Comment: Это не совсем то что мне нужно. Я бы хотел взращать эту кнопку программно.

Comment: Вы никак это не сделаете, боты тут не при чём. Пишите Дурову, ну или делайте свой мессенджер

Comment: Я видел такое в других ботах. Так что это возможно

Comment: Может пример хотя бы покажете? :)

Comment: Вам просто необходимо удалить первое сообщение отправленное пользователем, делается это с помощью записи message_id при первой команде `/start` от пользователя и последующим изыманием этого message_id и удалением сообщения. Вроде так

Comment: Бот удаляет первое сообщение пользователя, но кнопки все еще нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если добавить в ссылку на бота данные тогда появится эта кнопка.
Например обычная ссылка выглядит так `https://t.me/username_bot`. Чтоб передать данные пользуемся документацией https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking. Выходит что нам стоит только подставить нужную переменну ( зависит от ситуации, или просто любую елси вам не нужно ее использовать ). В итоге получим это: `https://t.me/username_bot?start=Hello`